# Change height parameter of rickshaw rChart within Shiny tabPanel to avoid scrollbar

Tags: r, shiny, rickshaw, rcharts

I am building a small Shiny application in which my `mainPanel` contains a `tabsetPanel`, and one of the tabs is a rickshaw rChart. If I don't have tabs and only display the rChart, everything is fine, but when the rChart is contained in a tab the tab is always shorter than the chart, imposing a scrollbar.

I've abbreviated the below code with elipses to focus on the important parts:

ui.R:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("..."),

  sidebarPanel(...),

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Plot",
        div(id = "myplot",
            includeCSS("rickshaw.css"),
            showOutput("plot", "rickshaw"))
      ),
      tabPanel("Raw Data", tableOutput("table"))
    )
  )
))  # end shinyUI
```

server.R:

```
# some preprocessing up here

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # generate checkbox options from preprocessed data
  output$modelSelection <- renderUI({...})

  # make the rickshaw rChart
  output$plot <- renderChart2({

    chart <- Rickshaw$new()
    chart$layer(value ~ datetime, group = "variable", data = select.frame, type="area")
    chart$set(width = 600,
              height = 400,
              slider = TRUE)
    return(chart)
  })

  # make the raw output
  output$table <- renderTable({...})    
})
```

where `rickshaw.css` and `renderChart2` come from [this github bug](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/146) to enable interactivity.

So the problem is that while the height in `chart$set` DOES work, the actual tab is always slightly shorter, forcing a scroll bar (still true when `slider=FALSE`).

I had a similar problem with tabbed ggplot's in the past, which was fixed by passing a height argument to `plotOutput` which is not an option with `showOutput`.

I have found [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610322/change-height-attributes-of-graph-produced-with-rcharts-for-use-with-rshiny) [fixes](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/254) which apparently work for morris.js, but I've been unable to adapt them properly.

Has anyone else has better success with rickshaw and tabbed panels?
I'm using `rCharts_0.4.2` and `shiny_0.8.0` on `R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the height as a percentage for example:

```
 chart$set(width = 600
          ,height = "100%"
          ,slider = TRUE)
```

You may also want to make some styling adjustments to the `tabPanel`

```
 tabPanel("Plot",
           div(id = "myplot", style = "display:inline;position:absolute"
               ,showOutput("plot", "rickshaw"))
 ),
```

Comment: The height-as-percentage didn't work for me, with or without the `style` parameter; it stretched out the plot but condensed the actual stacked colors. The style adjustment alone, however, was perfect. Thanks!

Comment: have you found a way to do it by using % instead of using px?